# Magento2 reindex from backend

Tags: magento2, reindex

I don't see any options to reindex from backend.

Will it always have to be done via ssh? This is a big pain because our store owners should have the option to reindex from backend, we don't want to fix it for them every time there is an index issue.

So my question: is this a bug to be fixed or is it a design decision and live with it?
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1075

What about if you don't have crons on your server like many small clients do?

Comment: You have to re-indexing by cmd command.

Comment: @SHPatel my question is different

Comment: Know this is not question but for reference the cmd line option is  bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: In case you don't have SSH access and no cron (which is nothing but recommended) you can reindex from the backend like this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/139088/2380

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism nice one. should put it on packagist for a composer install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cron is all but required now. You will run into a lot of problems with your store if you do not have Magento's cron scheduler set up and running as intended, indexing just one of them.

Being unable to reindex from the admin panel is a design decision carried over from EE 1.13-1.14. It's unlikely to change back.

Under normal circumstances, with indexes all set to 'update on save', it shouldn't be necessary to reindex in the first place. They will all be partial-updated immediately with product changes.

Comment: thanks. this is sad. we have update on save on 1.x too and sometimes the changes don't show up and you need to reindex. I just hope that 2 will be more reliable. We just can't give ssh credentials to clients to fool around.

Comment: Same seems to happen with Magento 2.1.7. Update on save does not work properly. I have to manually run indexer with console in order to get new products to show.

Answer (score 3):

There are free modules to add reindexing functionality to backend. For instance, [Reindex by DigitalPianism](https://github.com/digitalpianism/reindex)

Answer (score 0):

Check this article [Magento 2: How to add reindex option to Index Management grid?](https://www.hungersoft.com/info/add-reindex-option-to-index-management-grid-in-magento2) . You can also download the finished code from [github](https://github.com/hungersoft/magento2-admin-reindex) or [hungersoft.com](https://www.hungersoft.com/p/magento2-admin-reindexer)